# How to extract album cover from a mp3 file without download the whole file

Tags: c++, mp3, gstreamer, taglib

I'm using TabLib for extraction, but i need to know how many bytes should i download from the mp3 file, in order to be able to extract TagLib.

I've looked into mp3 specs, but i didn't found anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 99% of cases, if you pull down first the first 10 bytes, you'd then have the ID3v2 header, of which the last 4 bytes will be the size of the ID3v2 tag, which will contain the cover art.

The ID3v2 size is a "sync-safe integer", but TagLib has a function to decode that to a normal integer:

```
TagLib::ID3v2::SynchData::toUInt(const ByteVector &data)
```

So, basically the algorithm would be:

- Grab the first 10 bytes
- Sanity check those bytes that they start with "ID3"
- Read the last 4 bytes of those 10 and pass them through the function above to get the ID3v2 tag length
- Grab that much additional data from the stream
- Pass that block of data to TagLib
- Extract the cover art

Answer (score 1):

The mp3 specification doesn't really have meta-data like song name, or album art. It's part of [id3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id3), and it's normally placed at the end of the file.

Comment: False. ID3v2 tags, which are the ones that are able to contain album art, are almost universally at the beginning of the file.